# Impact 360 videos are distorted and several horizontal black lines show on monitor

Tags: windows-7, laptop, virtualbox, video, multiple-monitors

This is a very specific issue, so I'm not sure if anyone else has experienced this or not, but all suggestions are welcome.

In our company, we use a web application called Impact 360 by Verint, which allows us to record customer calls as well as video screenshots of the agent's desktops while they're on a call.

If a supervisor is trying to view a video recording while on a laptop that is hooked up to an external monitor either directly to the laptop or through a docking station, the videos will be severely distorted and unwatchable.

The biggest dilemma in troubleshooting is that only certain supervisors have this issue and it's only with certain agents. For example, 10 of 30 supervisors have this issue and it's with 40 of 100 agents. They are not able to view any videos for any of the trouble agents, while they can view all of the videos for the non-trouble agents. All of the agents are in VDI using the same template and they login to a different VM each time they login.

I have had the supervisors try different, newly imaged computers with the same result. I also tried recreating the VDI profiles for trouble agents. I've updated video drivers to the latest version, tried different resolutions and refresh rates, as well as reinstalled the Impact 360 playback software, which is necessary for playback in the web interface.

The agents with distorted videos have a mix of monitor sizes and models, as well as single and dual displays. All of the supervisors are using a laptop on docking stations connected to a 19" monitor. All hardware is Dell, and Windows 7 x64 Pro is the only OS used.

The videos will play clearly in the following scenarios:

- Change the displays from extended to duplicate in the display properties (right-click desktop and choose “Screen Resolution”)
- Show display only on the laptop or the desktop, but not both at the same time
- Remove the laptop from the docking station
- Download the recordings to the computer and play them using Windows Media Player

Another odd issue is that if the video is played while sitting on the external monitor, it will cause that monitor to have a dozens of small (1cm long) black lines evenly spaced throughout the display, but the laptop screen will be fine. It will stay like that until a good video is played, after which the lines will disappear. If playing the video from the laptop display, no lines will appear.

I would appreciate any advice that anyone can provide.

Thanks, Shawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My company uses this software as well and we had plenty of issues after upgrading all our CSR users to the latest version.

One thing we found that affected whether recordings could be played was running in Internet Explorer x86 or x64. Verint only worked in IE9 (or higher, with compatibility view on) as well.

Make sure to check the registry [HKLM>Software>Witness Systems>eQuality Agent>Capture>CurrentVersion (for x86 Verint)] and make sure that the software is pointing to the servers that your company uses. Port number should be :29522.

- 64-bit version of Verint will have the reg entries under Wow6432Node directory

Also make sure that everyone is running the latest version of all the components. Our company is currently up to:

> Desktop Resources Verint - 11.2.0
>
> Logger - 11.01.2001
>
> Playback - 11.02.00.1000
>
> Screen Capture Module - 11.02.0000.893

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I checked the registry and the server/port number value is correct.  All of our users are still using IE9 (for about another week), and I also tested it with IE11 in compatibility mode with no luck.  We are slightly behind in the software versions, so we'll have to look at upgrading those, as I can't think of anything else that could possibly resolve this issue.

Comment: We in IT have to go through someone in the call center to contact their rep in Verint to obtain the latest software, so it may be awhile before we can get that upgraded, but once we do, I'll post my response here to confirm whether that worked or not.  Any other suggestions would be welcomed as well :)

Comment: I updated the Playback module from 11.11.5145 to 11.11.6813 (provided by Verint) and that resolved the issue.  There is no more video distortion when viewing recordings in the browser.